Rectangular region biquadratic Lagrangian interpolation basis to solve dirichlet boundary Poisson equation?
after learning FEM,I try using it to solve a PDE $-\Delta u=f,u=0 on \partial\Omega$,where $\Omega$ is a square with $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$being its vertex by classical finite elements.Here I use the biquadratic Lagrangian interpolation basis with node being$[0,0],[0,1/2],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1/2],[1,1],[1/2,0],[1/2,1/2],[1/2,1]$.I caculate the basis,build the mesh,matrix A,array F,and then i get value at the node U=A\F ,however I find it is false, as the order of the covergence <<1.
here is my code:

x=linspace(0,1,N+1);y=x;
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
pointlist=reshape([x,y],(N+1)^2,2); 
f1=@(x,y)sin(pi.*x).*sin(pi.*y);
u1=@(x,y)sin(pi.*x).*sin(pi.*y)/2/pi^2;
u1x=@(x,y)cos(pi.*x).*sin(pi.*y)/2/pi;
u1y=@(x,y)sin(pi.*x).*cos(pi.*y)/2/pi;

phi1=@(x,y)4.*(x-1/2).*(x-1).*(y-1/2).*(y-1);%0,0
phi2=@(x,y)-8.*x.*(x-1).*(y-1/2).*(y-1);%1/2,0
phi3=@(x,y)4.*x.*(x-1/2).*(y-1/2).*(y-1);%1,0
phi4=@(x,y)-8.*x.*(x-1/2).*y.*(y-1);%1,1/2
phi5=@(x,y)4.*x.*(x-1/2).*y.*(y-1/2);%1,1
phi6=@(x,y)-8.*x.*(x-1).*y.*(y-1/2);%1/2,1
phi7=@(x,y)4.*(x-1/2).*(x-1).*y.*(y-1/2);%0,1
phi8=@(x,y)-8.*(x-1/2).*(x-1).*y.*(y-1);%0,1/2
phi9=@(x,y)16.*x.*(x-1).*y.*(y-1);%1/2,1/2

phi1x=@(x,y)4.*(2.*x-3/2).*(y-1/2).*(y-1);
phi2x=@(x,y)-8.*(2.*x-1).*(y-1/2).*(y-1);
phi3x=@(x,y)4.*(2.*x-1/2).*(y-1/2).*(y-1);
phi4x=@(x,y)-8.*(2.*x-1/2).*y.*(y-1);
phi5x=@(x,y)4.*(2.*x-1/2).*y.*(y-1/2);
phi6x=@(x,y)-8.*(2.*x-1).*y.*(y-1);
phi7x=@(x,y)4.*(2.*x-3/2).*y.*(y-1/2);
phi8x=@(x,y)-8.*(2.*x-3/2).*y.*(y-1);
phi9x=@(x,y)16.*(2.*x-1).*y.*(y-1);

phi1y=@(x,y)4.*(x-1/2).*(x-1).*(2.*y-3/2);
phi2y=@(x,y)-8.*x.*(x-1).*(2.*y-3/2);
phi3y=@(x,y)4.*x.*(x-1/2).*(2.*y-3/2);
phi4y=@(x,y)-8.*x.*(x-1/2).*(2.*y-1);
phi5y=@(x,y)4.*x.*(x-1/2).*(2.*y-1/2);
phi6y=@(x,y)-8.*x.*(x-1).*(2.*y-1/2);
phi7y=@(x,y)4.*(x-1/2).*(x-1).*(2.*y-1/2);
phi8y=@(x,y)-8.*(x-1/2).*(x-1).*(2.*y-1);
phi9y=@(x,y)16.*x.*(x-1).*(2.*y-1);

Phi={phi1,phi2,phi3,phi4,phi5,phi6,phi7,phi8,phi9};
Phix={phi1x,phi2x,phi3x,phi4x,phi5x,phi6x,phi7x,phi8x,phi9x};
Phiy={phi1y,phi2y,phi3y,phi4y,phi5y,phi6y,phi7y,phi8y,phi9y};

Ixx=zeros(9);Iyy=zeros(9);

for i=1:9
for j=1:9
v1=Phix{i};v2=Phix{j};
w1=Phiy{i};w2=Phiy{j};
Ixx(i,j)=quad2d(@(x,y)v1(x,y).*v2(x,y),0,1,0,1);
Iyy(i,j)=quad2d(@(x,y)w1(x,y).*w2(x,y),0,1,0,1);
end
end


nb=N^2;
NB=zeros(nb,4);
A=zeros((2.*N+1)^2);F=zeros((2.*N+1)^2,1);u=zeros((2.*N+1)^2,1);

for i=1:N
for j=1:N
NB((i-1)*N+j,1)=(i-1)*(N+1)+j;
NB((i-1)*N+j,2)=i*(N+1)+j;
NB((i-1)*N+j,3)=i*(N+1)+j+1;
NB((i-1)*N+j,4)=(i-1)*(N+1)+j+1;
end
end
pl=zeros(0,2);

np=(N+1)^2;

for m=1:nb
a=NB(m,1);b=NB(m,2);c=NB(m,3);d=NB(m,4);
xa=pointlist(a,1);xb=pointlist(b,1);xc=pointlist(c,1);xd=pointlist(d,1);
ya=pointlist(a,2);yb=pointlist(b,2);yc=pointlist(c,2);yd=pointlist(d,2);

x1=1/2.*(xa+xb);y1=1/2.*(ya+yb);
x2=1/2.*(xb+xc);y2=1/2.*(yb+yc);
x3=1/2.*(xc+xd);y3=1/2.*(yc+yd);
x4=1/2.*(xd+xa);y4=1/2.*(yd+ya);
x0=1/4*(x1+x2+x3+x4);y0=1/4*(y1+y2+y3+y4);
p1=[x1,y1];p2=[x2,y2];p3=[x3,y3];p4=[x4,y4];
p5=[x0,y0];

if size(pl,1)==0
pl=[pl;p1];
s=size(pl,1);
NB(m,5)=np+s;
end

s1=1;s2=1;s3=1;s4=1;s5=1;

for l=1:size(pl,1)
if(p1(1,1)==pl(l,1)&&p1(1,2)==pl(l,2))
s1=0;t1=l;
end
end
if(s1)
pl=[pl;p1];
NB(m,5)=np+size(pl,1);
end
if(s1==0)
NB(m,5)=t1+np;
end


for l=1:size(pl,1)
if(p2(1,1)==pl(l,1)&&p2(1,2)==pl(l,2))
s2=0;t2=l;
end
end
if(s2)
pl=[pl;p2];
NB(m,6)=np+size(pl,1);
end
if(s2==0)
NB(m,6)=t2+np;
end

for l=1:size(pl,1)
if(p3(1,1)==pl(l,1)&&p3(1,2)==pl(l,2))
s3=0;t3=l;
end
end
if(s3)
pl=[pl;p3];
NB(m,7)=np+size(pl,1);
end
if(s3==0)
NB(m,7)=t3+np;
end

for l=1:size(pl,1)
if(p4(1,1)==pl(l,1)&&p4(1,2)==pl(l,2))
s4=0;t4=l;
end
end
if(s4)
pl=[pl;p4];
NB(m,8)=np+size(pl,1);
end
if(s4==0)
NB(m,8)=t4+np;
end

for l=1:size(pl,1)
if(p5(1,1)==pl(l,1)&&p5(1,2)==pl(l,2))
s5=0;t5=l;
end
end
if(s5)
pl=[pl;p5];
NB(m,9)=np+size(pl,1);
end
if(s5==0)
NB(m,9)=t5+np;
end
end

pl=[pointlist;pl];
np=size(pl,1);

Delta=1/N^2;
Xx=N;Yy=N;


for m=1:nb
a=NB(m,1);b=NB(m,2);c=NB(m,3);d=NB(m,4);
e=NB(m,5);f=NB(m,6);g=NB(m,7);h=NB(m,8);
o=NB(m,9);

xa=pl(a,1);ya=pl(a,2);
xb=pl(b,1);yb=pl(b,2);
xc=pl(c,1);yc=pl(c,2);
xd=pl(d,1);yd=pl(d,2);
xe=pl(e,1);ye=pl(e,2);
xf=pl(f,1);yf=pl(f,2);
xg=pl(g,1);yg=pl(g,2);
xh=pl(h,1);yh=pl(h,2);
xo=pl(o,1);yo=pl(o,2);

ni={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,o};
for l1=1:9
   for l2=1:9
i=ni{l1};j=ni{l2};
A(i,j)=A(i,j)+Delta.*(Ixx(l1,l2)*(Xx^2)+Iyy(l1,l2)*(Yy^2));
   end
end


X=@(x,y)xa+1/N.*x;
Y=@(x,y)ya+1/N.*y;


for l3=1:9
l=ni{l3};
v1=Phi{l3};
fphi=@(x,y)f1(X(x,y),Y(x,y)).*v1(x,y);
F(l,1)=F(l,1)+quad2d(fphi,0,1,0,1)*Delta;
end
end

for i=1:np
xi=pl(i,1);yi=pl(i,2);
if(xi==0||yi==0||xi==1||yi==1)
A(:,i)=0;A(i,:)=0;A(i,i)=1;F(i)=0;
end
end

for i=1:np
xi=pl(i,1);yi=pl(i,2);
u(i,1)=u1(xi,yi);
end

U=A\F;
einf=norm(u-U,inf);


I just do not know where the mistake happens.My question is about matlab,finite elements method,and poisson equation.
